# Active directory fears

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts, user-profile

I want to implement active directory in my organization but my major challenge is that i have already installed an application on the server(windows 2016 server standard) that uses sql 2012 and sql management studio already . Also there are about 50 client computers that would be added to the AD but they already have applications such as outlook client and other office applications. So the main question is what would be the effect  it would have on the user profiles on the clients  and the server if i go ahead and configure active directory on the server. Please forgive the noob question i just hope i could get answers

Answer (score 0):

You can let user profiles remain local and not roam them up to the server.

The server will be busier when servicing authentication, DNS and DHCP (how do you do that today?). If it's got excess capacity it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When you join a PC to an Active Directory Domain and log in with the new AD user account a brand new AD user profile is created on the PC.  You may either manually copy all of the files (Documents, Desktop, Favorites, Outlook PST (in AppData), etc. from the old local profile to the new AD user profile OR you can use the built in Profile Copy utility in `Control Panel>> System & Security>> System>> Advance system security`.  In that location under `Settings>> User Profiles` select the local user profile you want to copy and follow the wizard to copy the profile information to the new AD user profile.  Obviously you will need to have logged into the computer with the new AD user account at least once prior in order to create the new AD user profile before you can copy any data to it. Additionally, you will want to complete the copy operations (with either method) while logged on to the PC with a third user account that has either local admin or Domain Admin permissions on the PC.

There are third party tools that can assist you as well.  There may well be some settings and/or information that does not copy correctly so be ready to manually move and reconfigure those items the end users cannot.  There is little to no risk of data loss in normal circumstances since the old local user profile is not deleted in this process.